# Play a sound loop when push notification arrived

Tags: android, service, push-notification

I have following problem:
I search a soluten where i can play a sound loop when a push notification arrived.
The sound should play every 5 secounds until the user brings the app into focus again.

Whats the best and reliable way to do this?
It should have the lowest possible latency.

Should i use Services?
The used android versions goes from 5 - 11
(all coded in Java, Push notifications comes from Pushy not FCM)

Thanks for any reply :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'd better use Android's `AlarmManager`

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager):

> AlarmManager provides access to the system alarm services. These allow you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the future.

You can learn more about it [here](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/alarmmanager).